# Unexpected UTF-8 BOM Deploy Django-app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying deploy my Django application to [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/). I've done 
almost all the steps in this [tutorial](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/). But when I try to finish the last step([$ git push heroku master](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/#deploy-to-heroku)) , Heroku returned the following error:

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     The latest version of Python 3.6 is python-3.6.6 (you are using python-3.7.0, which is unsupported).
 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.6).
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.7.0
-----> Installing pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 12, in main
    lockfile = json.load(f)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    s, 0)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

What can cause it? how can I fix it? can it result from a bad python version (recommended is 3.6.6 but i have 3.7)? or if someone had a similar problem, where he was looking for a solution?
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     The latest version of Python 3.6 is python-3.6.6 (you are using python-3.6.6, which is unsupported).
 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.6).
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.6.6
 !     Requested runtime (python-3.6.6) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Looks like you are decoding something as JSON, which is not JSON or even text at all, but a binary file.

Comment: do you know maybe, how to check in which folder is he located?

Comment: change your runtime.txt to use `python-3.6.6` and there is a JSON file. did you use the `dumpdata` command. if yes, reopen the generated json file and resave it with `utf-8` encoding

Comment: No, i'm not use the command 'dumpdata'. I changed the version of Python but my deploy process ended even earlier. I added the answer from the log above.
EDIT:

I will try to go through the whole process again. The message is very strange('3.6 is python-3.6.6 (you are using python-3.6.6') ...